# Has anyone tried running IronRuby.Rack through Kayak?

Tags: .net, webserver, ironruby, rack

I recently learned about [kayak](http://kayakhttp.com/), an HTTP server written in C# (i.e. not through IIS). I'm wondering if anyone has tried hooking up IronRuby to run Rack through this platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the author's condemning of System.Web, most likely not. IronRuby.Rack uses System.Web to hook into ASP.NET extensibility, enabling it to run on any System.Web-enabled web-server. If you want a lightweight web-server to run IronRuby.Rack on, it works fine with Cassini, which is bundled in the IronRuby.Rack gem.

Comment: Leaving this as the answer, but it looks as though someone eventually did this: https://github.com/nrk/rayak